# Using the Ember Inspector within a JS Bin

Tags: ember.js

How, if possible, do I use the Ember Inspector within a JSBin. I opened it up and it didnt detect anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pop the jsbin open in full screen using the arrow in the top right of the output window.